# Increase / Modify Max Upload File Size

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, file-upload, iis-7

We have a .NET application deployed on an Amazon ec2 instance running Windows Server 2012. There is an issue regarding the maximum file upload size, which is presently limited to a measly 30 MB.

To address this issue, we modified the application's web.config file per the following:

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
</requestFiltering>
</security>
<system.webServer>
```

Additionally, we double checked the IIS manager and validated that the maximum content length is also set to 2147483648 bytes there.

So what is left to change? I have heard that one option is to change the default global config settings at the system level, but I thought the whole point behind being able to modify these settings in IIS at the application level was to avoid having to do that.

There are numerous threads and forums where others have struggled with the 30MB upload limit, but the problems always seem to be solved using the settings outlined above. I'm wondering if this is a problem specific to Amazon, as we CAN handle larger file sizes on local servers.

Has anyone else had this issue and solved it, or is there anyone out there with ideas on how to address this? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576"
                  executionTimeout="600"
                  />
```